# Modified Depth-First-Search Python

Tags: python, recursion, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I'm looking to do a DFS through a graph to find nodes connected in a specific way.

```
graphed = {
    1: [25, 30], 2: [11], 3: [13], 4: [17], 5: [17],
    6: [26], 7: [11, 12], 8: [10, 13], 9: [14, 26],
   10: [8, 11, 15], 11: [2, 7, 10], 12: [7, 16, 17],
   13: [3, 8, 14], 14: [9, 13, 20], 15: [10, 19],
   16: [12, 18], 17: [4, 5, 12], 18: [16, 21, 22],
   19: [15, 28, 29], 20: [14, 25], 21: [18, 23],
   22: [18, 24], 23: [21, 27], 24: [22, 27], 25: [1, 20],
   26: [6, 9], 27: [23, 24], 28: [19], 29: [19], 30: [1]
}

letters = {
    'S': [1],
    'C': [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17],
              [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24],
              [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30] ],
    'O': [2, [3], [4], [5], [6]],
    'N': [7, [8], [9]]}


some_string = 'CO'

def dfs(graph, start, num, visited = None):
    # depth first search for connected nodes
    k = some_string[num]
    y = some_string[(num+1)]
    if visited is None:
        visited = []

    if start in visited:
        return

    visited.append(start)
    # if start corresponds to first letter of string, continue
    if start in letters.get(k):
        # find all nodes that it is connected too
        for each in [x for x in graph[start] if x not in visited]:
            # if any of the connected nodes correspond to
            #   the next letter of string, continue...
            if [each] in letters.get(y):
                dfs(graph, each, (num+1), visited) #recursion

    return visited

lst1 = []
for i in range(1,len(graphed)): 
     lst1.append(dfs(graphed, i, 0))
print(lst1)
```

Currently, all that is returned by the DFS function is the original start value, for i in range.

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],
 [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20],
 [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29]]
```

I expect this:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],
 [11, 2], [12], [13,3], [14], [15], [16], [17,4], [17,5],
 [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26,6],
 [27], [28], [29]]
```

To clarify: I expect the program to run the dfs function; if the start value is a value in 'C', find all nodes connected and check if they're in 'O'; if they are, do the dfs with them; if not, return the single value.

Hopefully this is clear, I can't get my head around why it won't work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code.  I recommend that you start over and use incremental programming: write a few lines of code, debug them, and don't continue until they work the way you want.  You're not getting some of the functionality your comments seem to assume.

1. I'm not sure that your list of visited nodes operates as you want.  This gets reset every time you return to the **for** loop in your main program.
2. Your main program doesn't hit the last node, 30.
3. I suspect that your main problem is your node notation.  I'm not sure what you intend with a list such as **[7, [8], [9]]**, where the node numbers are on different levels of nesting, but your logic seems to assume that there is no nesting.  You don't find some things because, for example, you search for element **11** in the list **[10, [11], [12], ...]** -- and this is *False*.  **[11]** is an element of the latter list, but **11** is not.

See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

I've done a little debugging, including changing some variable names to something more meaningful.  Here's what I have at the moment, strictly low-tech print statements.

```
graphed = {
    1: [25, 30], 2: [11], 3: [13], 4: [17], 5: [17],
    6: [26], 7: [11, 12], 8: [10, 13], 9: [14, 26],
   10: [8, 11, 15], 11: [2, 7, 10], 12: [7, 16, 17],
   13: [3, 8, 14], 14: [9, 13, 20], 15: [10, 19],
   16: [12, 18], 17: [4, 5, 12], 18: [16, 21, 22],
   19: [15, 28, 29], 20: [14, 25], 21: [18, 23],
   22: [18, 24], 23: [21, 27], 24: [22, 27], 25: [1, 20],
   26: [6, 9], 27: [23, 24], 28: [19], 29: [19], 30: [1]
}

letters = {
    'S': [1],
    'C': [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17],
              [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24],
              [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30] ],
    'O': [2, [3], [4], [5], [6]],
    'N': [7, [8], [9]]}


node_path = 'CO'

def dfs(graph, start, num, visited = None):
    print("ENTER dfs", start, num, visited)
    # depth first search for connected nodes
    start_ltr = node_path[num]
    end_ltr = node_path[(num+1)]
    if visited is None:
        visited = []

    if start in visited:
        return

    visited.append(start)
    # if start corresponds to first letter of string, continue
    print("  search for start node", start, "in list", start_ltr, letters.get(start_ltr))
    if start in letters.get(start_ltr):
        # find all nodes that it is connected too
        for each in [x for x in graph[start] if x not in visited]:
            print("    found", each, "in", graph[start]) 
            print("    search in list", end_ltr, letters.get(end_ltr))
            # if any of the connected nodes correspond to
            #   the next letter of string, continue...
            if [each] in letters.get(end_ltr):
                dfs(graph, each, (num+1), visited) #recursion

    print("LEAVE dfs", visited)
    return visited

lst1 = []
for i in range(1,15):    # I cut back the list for less output.
     lst1.append(dfs(graphed, i, 0))
print(lst1)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 so.py
ENTER dfs 1 0 None
  search for start node 1 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [1]
ENTER dfs 2 0 None
  search for start node 2 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [2]
ENTER dfs 3 0 None
  search for start node 3 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [3]
ENTER dfs 4 0 None
  search for start node 4 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [4]
ENTER dfs 5 0 None
  search for start node 5 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [5]
ENTER dfs 6 0 None
  search for start node 6 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [6]
ENTER dfs 7 0 None
  search for start node 7 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [7]
ENTER dfs 8 0 None
  search for start node 8 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [8]
ENTER dfs 9 0 None
  search for start node 9 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [9]
ENTER dfs 10 0 None
  search for start node 10 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
    found 8 in [8, 11, 15]
    search in list O [2, [3], [4], [5], [6]]
    found 11 in [8, 11, 15]
    search in list O [2, [3], [4], [5], [6]]
    found 15 in [8, 11, 15]
    search in list O [2, [3], [4], [5], [6]]
LEAVE dfs [10]
ENTER dfs 11 0 None
  search for start node 11 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [11]
ENTER dfs 12 0 None
  search for start node 12 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [12]
ENTER dfs 13 0 None
  search for start node 13 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [13]
ENTER dfs 14 0 None
  search for start node 14 in list C [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]]
LEAVE dfs [14]
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14]]
```

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 1):

Your `letters` dictionary is malformed.

```
'C': [10, [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17],
          [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24],
          [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30] ],
'O': [2, [3], [4], [5], [6]],
'N': [7, [8], [9]]}
```

Note how the first number for each letter is directly in the top-level list, but every other entry is in a sublist by itself. As a result, `if start in letters.get(k)` will be false for every C node that potentially connects to an O.

```
>>> 10 in letters.get("C")
True
>>> 11 in letters.get("C")
False
```

So I changed the dictionary to this:

```
letters = {
    'S': [1],
    'C': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    'O': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'N': [7, 8, 9]}
```

You'll have to change this line accordingly:

```
if [each] in letters.get(y):
```

To

```
if each in letters.get(y):
```

Also, to get the results of each recursion call to actually be passed back up, I had to change this line:

```
dfs(graph, each, (num+1), visited) #recursion
```

To

```
return dfs(graph, each, (num+1), visited) #recursion
```

Finally, add a special case at the top of the method for when all of `some_string` has been found:

```
def dfs(graph, start, num, visited = None):
    # depth first search for connected nodes
    if (num+1 == len(some_string)):
        return visited + [start]
```

At this point, the search was successful, so there are no more letters to search for!